# Many recent Questions asking for a stronger basis

Tags: discussion

I recently started using Philosophy SE and wanted to ask about what seems to be many questions asking for more basis for correct answers in Philosophy. For example, in a recent one about the Principle of Sufficient Reason, there was an answer, then the OP asks in a comment if there was something more grounding the statement that basically, "humans function this way".

Another poster has asked repeatedly the same question and won't accept anything that doesn't smell like a solid granite massif of logic that compels the brain of all sentients to acknowledge it. Which, of course, doesn't exist.

Does Philosophy SE often get this sort of searching plea for secure reasons to believe things? I wonder what is happening for people.

Comment: This site is more a place for people to ask about the commonly discussed and defended positions on some subject, rather than a place for people to advance their own personal views. So it is not surprising to me that an OP should ask for some additional grounds, or references, or quotes from eminent philosophers.

Comment: @Bumble I guess it felt to me more like a need to get out of existential terror rather than wanting more references.